# Unexpected behaviour of query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
@lists = List.joins("LEFT JOIN items ON lists.id = items.list_id").group("lists.id").order("items.priority")
```

I have two entities Lists and Items.
Each item is associated to a list. Now I'm viewing lists and items in table form
in which the header of the table contains list names and `<tbody>` contains item names for that particular list , each item has some priority(e.g 1,2,3..) while saving it. Now while displaying i want to sort items by their priority but my query is sorting lists by priority. Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are fetching the `List`s, and joining them with the `Item`s. Because of the way ActiveRecord works, you'll get a list of `List`s as result, with the `Item`s embedded.

If you want to loop over the items, you need to load the items and not the lists.

```
@items = Item.includes(:list).order("priority")
```

The example above uses `includes` to [eager load](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations) the associated list records and avoid the N+1 query issue.

Answer (score 1):

The following statement will give you all records in lists table and also eager load the associated items (ordered by priority) with each of them.

```
@lists = List.includes(:items).order('items.priority')
```

You can access the items ordered by priority in a list by making a call like:

```
list.items # where list is one of the records in @lists
```